# How to figure out how a node.js code is running?

Tags: node.js, logging, server, process, virtual-machine

there is an existing node.js code running as a continuous process on a ubuntu vm, for which I would like to see the logs.

So first I would like to know how this process is started/running.I tried with

```
 ps -aef | grep node
```

output is

```
arun 20897     1  0 Oct13 ?        07:03:06 node Monitor/Broker.js
```

can some one help me with how do i find how this process is started/running so that I can see the logs of that process.I am from python background and spare me if the question is very basic.

Comment: If node.js runs as a windows service, locate it in windows services, stop it, and then open command line, go the the path of the node server.js file and run 'node server.js'. You can see the logs there

Comment: its running on a ubuntu vm

Comment: you can manage it via pm2, it could help you in this case....

Answer (score 1):

Use pm2 (Process manager for running node js )
pm2 will keep track on node js process and will show when node js process was started and all the logs created by that process.

1) Install PM2 using `npm i pm2`
2) `pm2 start app.js`
3) To check how many node processes are running hit `pm2 list`
4)for stop, restart and delete
 `pm2 stop     <app_name|id|>`
 `pm2 restart  <app_name|id|>`
 `pm2 delete   <app_name|id|>`
5) To monitor `pm2 monit`

for reference use https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Comment: will `pm2 list` help if the node process which is already running didnot start by pm2 start filename.js ?

Comment: because I have done `pm2 list` but my existing process didn't get listed.

Comment: check with `ps -ae` command and then try with superuser  `sudo pm2 list`